# 9 speed SRAM shifter for dropbars?

Tags: shifter, cyclocross, sram, touring-bikes

Does anyone know if SRAM makes a 9 speed compatible shifter for dropbars? What's the best option for shifter/derailleurs for a 2x9 cross bike?

Comment: Why would it need to be SRAM?

Comment: If you are asking about 9 speed specifically it implies you have a 9 speed derailleur. Can you tell us what that derailleur is?

Answer (score 2):

SRAM's current lowest-level groupset is Apex, which is a ten-speed setup and [Rider_X says](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52439/9-speed-sram-shifter-for-dropbars/52440?noredirect=1#comment114715_52440) that SRAM have never made a nine-speed road groupset. Campagnolo also only seem to offer ten- and eleven-speed, so Shimano Sora is the only nine-speed in the current line-ups of the big three.

Comment: SRAM road started with 10 speeds. Lower speeds were only for mountain bikes or flat bar bikes.

Answer (score 1):

Shimano Shifters aren't compatible with SRAM derailleurs, so you have to get a travel adapter to alter to the cable pull. [Jtek Engineering](http://www.jtekengineering.com/) makes a bunch of different travel adapters. You should contact them to see if they have a solution.

I clicked around on a few of the travel adapters, but I couldn't be sure which one would for sure solve you problem.  The [Shiftmate 6](http://www.jtekengineering.com/shiftmate/shiftmate-6/) looks like it might work as it says it's used for 9 speed shimano shifters with a SRAM 1:1 derailleur and a shimano/SRAM 9 speed cassette.  [SRAM](https://www.sram.com/sram/mountain/technologies/1..1) lists a bunch of different derailleurs that use the 1:1 technology.